# Why isn't there a pressure near DC wires from the Doppler effect?

Tags: electromagnetism

Suppose I have a charged object ("the detector") at rest near an infinitely long, perfectly straight, neutral wire carrying a significant amount of DC current. As I understand things, the neutrality of the wire (equal density of protons and electrons) means there's no static force, the fields are constant so there's no induction, and the detector is at rest so there's no magnetic force, summing up to a net force of zero on the detector.

But I was reading about Liénard–Wiechert potentials the other day and thinking about the way that the scalar potential is different depending on whether the source is moving towards or away from the detector, which I believe is often described as a relativistic Doppler effect(?). Various sources have confirmed that an electron moving towards the detector will exert a stronger electric force than one moving away.

If this is the case, why isn't there a net force from nearby current on the detector thanks to the approaching electrons overpowering the retreating ones?

Thanks in advance for helping resolve my confusion!

Comment: You assumptions (no static force, zero force on detector) are unphysical. The charged object "detector" will induce surface charge on the surface of the current-carrying wire, and there will be mutual electric attraction. Also, the Liénard-Wiechert potentials describe field of a small compact charged particle; field of a current-carrying wire is different and there is no good reason to talk about the Doppler effect, since the field of the current-carrying wire is static.

Comment: Also, there is no "over-powering". Electric field of a moving particle has high symmetry, for same distances, it is the same in the front as in the back.

Comment: > *"Various sources have confirmed that an electron moving towards the detector will exert a stronger electric force than one moving away."* This seems wrong. Can you link the source?

Comment: First of all, thanks for responding!

Most of my model is being informed by my study of Liénard–Wiechert potentials, which is perhaps where I'm being tripped up. I was naively assuming that I could model the wire as being composed of a collection of particles, each of which obey the Liénard–Wiechert equations. (I'm specifically referencing the 1/(1 - $n_s\cdot\beta_s$) on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li%C3%A9nard%E2%80%93Wiechert_potential#Equations) Upon reflection I think all my other sources may have assumed that "Relativistic Doppler effect" applied to fields and not just to light.

Comment: You're absolutely right that the detector will induce a surface charge on the wire, and they'll attract. Thanks for that correction. I'm mostly just trying to understand why there's no force along the axis parallel to the wire.

Comment: Liénard–Wiechert expressions give only potentials, if you are interested in forces, you need the formulae for electric and magnetic field strength, which can be derived from the LW potentials or can be found in textbooks on EM theory. Already the EM field of compact charged particle in rectilinear motion does not manifest the asymmetry you mention. In case the charged particle moves with constant velocity, the easiest way to find its field is to use the Lorentz transformation to the Coulomb field of static charge. There is no asymmetry in that field.

Comment: Doppler effect concerns periodic EM field such as harmonic plane or spherical wave. You can't observe the Doppler effect on the field of charge in rectilinear motion.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you! I was deriving the forces from the potentials, and got similar equations to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li%C3%A9nard%E2%80%93Wiechert_potential#Field_computation
I ignored the magnetic field, since I was examining a detector at rest, and set $\dot \beta$ to zero since the charge has a constant velocity. I also assumed the source charge was equal to $4\pi\epsilon_0$ so that it simplifies to:
$E = (n - \beta)/(\gamma^2 r^2 (1 - n\cdot\beta)^3)$

Where beta is the velocity of the source and n is the normal vector pointing from it to the detector.

Comment: $\gamma$ and $r$ are symmetric, I think, but $(1 - n\cdot\beta)^3$ is not, afaict. When the velocity of the source ($\beta$) aligns with the the vector pointing towards the detector, this term will become smaller than 1, and when it's anti-aligned (i.e. travelling in the opposite direction) it will be larger than 1. Perhaps the answer is in the numerator?

Comment: You're probably misinterpreting the formula, because $r$ there is actually retarded distance to the source particle, depending on time, and different for the point in front of the source particle than for the point in the back, even though they are the same distance from the particle. When you evaluate it in terms of static coordinates, that factor $n\cdot\beta$ has to disappear. For detailed explanation and picture of the field lines of moving charge, see https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_26.html

Comment: Ah! I got it! The page you linked to was already starting with a symmetrical formulation for the potential, but I was able to back up to https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_21.html#Ch21-S6 and see where the relevant factors cancel. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, this is tricky, so I wrote a little Python program using sympy to resolve it.  First here is a diagram of the calculation.  We would like to see how the electric field in the $x$ direction at the top vertex of the triangle cancels.  We assume there are moving charges, and at some point in time $t$ there is a charge $q$ at the two bottom vertices of the triangle.

[image: diagram of moving charge]

Now, the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_field#Arbitrarily_moving_point_charge) formula tells us the field from each charge in the $x$ direction is
$$E_x = \frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{(n_x - \beta)(1-\beta^2)}{(1-n_x\beta)^3 \|\vec{r}-\vec{r_s}\|^2}$$
where $\beta = v/c$, $n_x$ is the projection of a normal pointing from source to test charge on the direction of motion, and $\|\vec{r}-\vec{r_s}\|$ is the distance from the source to test charge.  Of course, this has to be computed at the **retarded time**.

Now, superficially, we may think that at this point in time $t$, since both charges at the bottom vertices are the same distance from the test charge, then in a future time when their electric field reaches the test charge, the electic fields in the $x$ direction will cancel.  But from the formula for $E_x$ we can see that doesn't cancel, because the sign of $n_x$ *inverts* giving different values.

So what's going on?  In order to see the cancellation, we must compute the contributions from these charges at the retarted time that led to the position in the triangle at time $t$!

Now, let's call these retarded times $t-\Delta t_1, t-\Delta t_2$ (for the left, right charge respectively.)  We get equations for $\Delta t_1, \Delta t_2$
$$\begin{split}
(d+\Delta t_1 \beta c)^2 + r^2 = c^2 (\Delta t_1)^2\\
(d-\Delta t_2 \beta c)^2 + r^2 = c^2 (\Delta t_2)^2
\end{split}$$
We solve these quadratic equations for $\Delta t_1, \Delta t_2$ taking the *positive* solutions corresponding to retarded time (there are negative solutions corresponding to advanced time.)

From this we can compute the retarded distances from source to test charge
$$\begin{split}
\|\vec{r} - \vec{r}_{s,1}\| = c \Delta t_1\\
\|\vec{r} - \vec{r}_{s,2}\| = c \Delta t_2
\end{split}$$
and the retarded projection of normals along the motion
$$\begin{split}
n_{x,1} = \frac{d + \Delta t_1 \beta c}{\|\vec{r} - \vec{r}_{s,1}\|}\\
n_{x,2} = \frac{-(d - \Delta t_2 \beta c)}{\|\vec{r} - \vec{r}_{s,2}\|}
\end{split}$$

After plugging all these values into the formula for $E_x$ we get
$$\begin{split}
E_{x,1}=\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{d(1-\beta^2)}{(d^2 + (1-\beta^2)r^2)^{3/2}}\\
E_{x,2}=-\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{d(1-\beta^2)}{(d^2 + (1-\beta^2)r^2)^{3/2}}
\end{split}$$
and lo-and-behold... they cancel :)

Below is the Python code used to do the computation

```
from sympy import init_printing, symbols, simplify, expand, collect, roots, pprint

init_printing(use_unicode=False)

d, dt1, dt2, beta, c, r = symbols('d delta_t1 delta_t2 beta c r', positive=True)

p1 = collect(expand((d + dt1 * beta * c)**2 + r**2 - c**2 * dt1**2), dt1)
p2 = collect(expand((d - dt2 * beta * c)**2 + r**2 - c**2 * dt2**2), dt2)

t1 = simplify(roots(p1, dt1, multiple=True)[1])
t2 = simplify(roots(p2, dt2, multiple=True)[1])

dist1 = simplify(c * t1)
dist2 = simplify(c * t2)

n1 = simplify((d + t1 * beta * c) / dist1)
n2 = simplify(-(d - t2 * beta * c) / dist2)

val1 = simplify((n1 - beta) * (1 - beta**2)/((1 - n1 * beta)**3 * dist1**2))
val2 = simplify((n2 - beta) * (1 - beta**2)/((1 - n2 * beta)**3 * dist2**2))

pprint(val1)
print()
pprint(val2)
print()
pprint(simplify(val1 + val2))
```